# Graphite Installation on MacOS Sierra 10.12.4

Tags: graphite

I do many tries to install graphite on my MacBook. I follow this tutorial 
https://gist.github.com/trusche/bfab931c538bd1a63c80

I install all mandatory packages, but it stops at this command: `python manage.py syncdb` 
There is no file named manage.py on my mac.

this file should be present in /opt/graphite/webapp/graphite.

I don't understand why this file is missing.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using a newer version of Graphite than the tutorial assumes. The command to configure the Django database changed a while back. It should be something like:

`django-admin.py migrate --settings=graphite.settings --run-syncdb`

See https://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config-database-setup.html for more information.